# Vector Space Basis with Set of Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How might I go about finding the basis of a vector spaced spanned by a set of three vectors? For example, if given the set of vectors $\{(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)\}$ how would I find the basis?

I've tried looking [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorSpaceBasis.html) but I'm still pretty confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use definition.

- Take any vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^3 $(or any $K$ you're working with) and see if it can be written as a linear combination of the given vectors.
- See if the given vectors are linearly independent. That is, you need to show that

$$a(1,2,3) + b(4,5,6) + c(7,8,9) = 0 \Rightarrow a= b = c = 0$$

where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So one possible basis is a=b=c=0?

Comment: No, $a,b,c$ are scalars on the field $\mathbb{R}$. What is the definition of basis set? Now think about the answer, see how it fits the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Since

$$(7,8,9)=2\cdot(4,5,6)-(1,2,3)$$ means $(7,8,9)$ is linear combination of $(1,2,3)$ and $(4,5,6).$ Since $(1,2,3)$ and $(4,5,6)$ are linearly independent, what is a possible basis?